# Sudden spike in "Error evaluating subsidiary query errors" for recurring queries

Tags: google-bigquery

We are running hundreds of canned SQL queries that query data on a sliding time window (e.g. the structure of the SQL remains the same). Yesterday around 21:09 - 21:13 saw a couple of hundred cases where BigQuery raised the error:
    {u'reason': u'invalidQuery', u'message': u'Error evaluating subsidiary    query', u'location': u'query'}

Today this happened again between 16:05 and 16:14 for even more queries.

The queries use TABLE_QUERY (note the escaped quotes):
    FROM TABLE_QUERY([bbbb], \'table_id in ("delivered_201607",   "delivered_201608")\'

Although as mentioned earlier, these queries are 'canned' in that the only part that changes are decorators and timestamp comparisons so it is peculiar the invalid query errors only occurred on the above two periods. e.g. if they are invalid they should always be invalid.

Is this Google BigQuery infrastructure related?

Comment: might be related - at exactly same time-frame i saw `{location=query, message=Timestamp evaluation: connection error., reason=invalidQuery}` errors on our scheduled queries running for past many months w/o any issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a short window during which there was an infrastructure issue. The problem was mitigated shortly after.

Comment: If there was an official incident, why is not coming up here? https://status.cloud.google.com/summary